# make: *** [port-target] Error 2 When trying to install GDAL for GeoDjango using Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: django, bash, ubuntu, gdal, geodjango

I am trying to install `GeoDjango` to use in my project. I am using `Ubuntu 18.04` through `VirtualBox`. I am also using the `GeoDjango` installlation Guide to [install Gdal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#gdal). I have `GEOS` and `PROJ.4` installled.

I have successfully run the below commands :

```
$ wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/1.11.2/gdal-1.11.2.tar.gz #success
$ tar xzf gdal-1.11.2.tar.gz #success
$ cd gdal-1.11.2 #success
```

Later I am supposed to do the below (according to the documentation):

```
$ ./configure
$ make # Go get some coffee, this takes a while.
$ sudo make install
$ cd ..
```

However, when I run these lines:

```
$ ./configure  #success
$ make # Go get some coffee, this takes a while. #ERROR SEE BELOW
```

I get the below error:

```
samir@samir-VirtualBox:~/gdal-1.11.2$ make # Go get some coffee, this takes a while.
  (cd port; make)
  make[1]: Entering directory '/home/samir/gdal-1.11.2/port'
  /bin/bash /home/samir/gdal-1.11.2/libtool --mode=compile --tag=CXX g++ -std=c++98 -g -O2 -DHAVE_SSE_AT_COMPILE_TIME  -Wall  -DOGR_ENABLED -I/home/samir/gdal-1.11.2/port   -I../frmts/zlib  -DHAVE_LIBZ -c -o cpl_error.lo cpl_error.cpp
  libtool: compile:  g++ -std=c++98 -g -O2 -DHAVE_SSE_AT_COMPILE_TIME -Wall -DOGR_ENABLED -I/home/samir/gdal-1.11.2/port -I../frmts/zlib -DHAVE_LIBZ -c cpl_error.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/cpl_error.o
  cpl_error.cpp: In function 'void CPLErrorV(CPLErr, int, const char*, __va_list_tag*)':
  cpl_error.cpp:190:20: error: incompatible types in assignment of '__va_list_tag*' to 'va_list {aka __va_list_tag [1]}'
         wrk_args = args;
                    ^~~~
  cpl_error.cpp:226:24: error: incompatible types in assignment of '__va_list_tag*' to 'va_list {aka __va_list_tag [1]}'
             wrk_args = args;
                        ^~~~
  ../GDALmake.opt:568: recipe for target 'cpl_error.lo' failed
  make[1]: *** [cpl_error.lo] Error 1
  make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/samir/gdal-1.11.2/port'
  GNUmakefile:53: recipe for target 'port-target' failed
  make: *** [port-target] Error 2
```

Below is a Screenshot of the error. so you can see it in color

[image]

How can I resolve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have ubuntu installed on your computer. If you
are using windows, install VirtualBox and download Ubuntu (Its a Linux
OS). You might have to do a basic course on Ubuntu either on YouTube
or Udemy then do

```
sudo apt install geos
sudo apt install proj4
sudo apt install gdal
sudo-apt install postgressql
sudo-apt install till postgis
```

that's it.. you are done as simple as that..

`then download pgadmin3` (pgadmin4 is not available on ubuntu at the
time of this comment)

```
make the database on pgadmin3 (its way simpler than psql)
```

In your Virtual Env do

```
pip install dj-database-url
pip install psycopg2
pip install pillow
```

I suffered 2 weeks figuring this out.. Hopefully you don't have to
 Trying this on Windows is next to impossible. Don't follow the
GeoDjango documents for installing GeoDjango with make and
make-install as that is very difficult.